# SQL stored procedure not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is the code for a stored procedure.

The first part of the code works as it is supposed to. It takes the variables, does an INSERT into one table, then with the primary key created from that action does another INSERT on a seperate table.

What doesn't happen, however, is the code in the if/else if/else block towards then end. It is basically supposed to check to make sure the two ID columns are matching properly. If not, it adjusts the columns to their appropriate values, and then returns the old values plus the date and user name (lastChangeOperator) of the person who made the entry.

I've spent all day writing this and another part of this program, so I'm hoping a second set of eyes will do the trick.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AgentIdAprCheck] 
  (
    @companyCode char(3),
    @agentId char(10),
    @firstName nvarChar(50),
    @lastname nvarChar(50),
    @suffix char(10),
    @ssn int, 
    @taxIdType char(1),
    @entityType char(1),
    @corporateName nvarChar(100),
    @currentUniqueId int OUTPUT,
    @currentAgentId int OUTPUT,
    @operator nvarchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @date datetime OUTPUT
  )
  AS
    DECLARE @rows int = 0
    DECLARE @uniqueAgentId int = 0
    DECLARE @lastChangeOperator char(6) = 'LVOMQ1'
    DECLARE @LastChangeDate datetime
    --DECLARE @currentUniqueId int = 0
    --DECLARE @currentAgent int = 0
    --DECLARE @operator nvarchar(50)
    --DECLARE @date datetime

    SELECT @rows = COUNT(AgentTaxId) 
      FROM AgentIdentification
      WHERE AgentTaxId = @ssn

    if @rows > 0
      return 1
    else
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      SET @LastChangeDate = GETDATE()
      INSERT INTO Agent (EntityType, FirstName, LastName, 
        NameSuffix, CorporateName, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
      VALUES (@entityType, @firstName, @lastname, 
        '', @corporateName, @lastChangeOperator, @LastChangeDate)

      SELECT @uniqueAgentId = @@IDENTITY
      SELECT UniqueAgentId
        FROM Agent

      INSERT INTO AgentIdentification (UniqueAgentId, TaxIdType, 
        AgentTaxId, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
      VALUES (@uniqueAgentId, @taxIdType, @ssn, @
        lastChangeOperator, @lastChangeDate)

      DECLARE @uniqueIdRows int = 0
      SELECT @uniqueIdRows = COUNT(UniqueAgentId)
    FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
    WHERE UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId

      DECLARE @agentIdRows int = 0
      SELECT @agentIdRows = COUNT(AgentId)
        FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
        WHERE AgentId = @agentId

      if @uniqueIdRows = 0 AND @agentIdRows = 0
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO UniqueAgentIdToAgentId (UniqueAgentId, AgentId, 
            CompanyCode, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
          VALUES (@uniqueAgentId, @agentId, @companyCode, 
            @lastChangeOperator, @LastChangeDate)
        END
      else if @agentIdRows = 0
        BEGIN           
          SELECT @currentUniqueId = UniqueAgentId, 
            @operator = LastChangeOperator, @date = @LastChangeDate
          FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId

          UPDATE UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
            SET UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId
            WHERE AgentId = @agentId AND UniqueAgentId = @currentUniqueId
        END
      else
        BEGIN           
          SELECT @currentAgentId = AgentId, 
            @operator = LastChangeOperator, @date = @LastChangeDate
          FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId

          UPDATE UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
            SET AgentId = @agentId
            WHERE  UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId --AND AgentId = @currentAgentId
          return 2
        END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: So none of the IF/ELSE IF/ELSE is running?  By default wouldn't the ELSE always run?  You also have a select statement and output parameters.  How are you handling the returned data?  Finally, have you stepped through to make sure the `uniqueIdRows` and `agentIdRows` variables are populating as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`? I'm guessing this may be your problem.

As Pinal Dave says [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

*"To avoid the potential problems associated with adding a trigger later on, always use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to return the identity of the recently added row in your T SQL Statement or Stored Procedure."*

Comment: [Scope identity sometimes returns incorrect value](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).  Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. From my own experience Scope_Identity fixed all my problems caused by using @@Identity, but I had not come across any failures with Scope_Identity. Now I won't be able to sleep at nights!